# Not able to add mouse hover effect using Material UI to react component where root is <Link> from react-router-dom and inside i have box & card comp

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hover

I am trying to add mouse hover effect to my react component using Material UI where my root component is  from react-router-dom and inside I have a box and card component. I tried using "&:hover" inside sx on the box component but the hover effect is not being displayed. This is what I tried:

```
import { Avatar, Box, Card, CardHeader } from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
function UserItem(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            "&:hover": {
              backgroundColor: "black",
              color: "white",
            },
          }}
        >
          <Card sx={{ width: 300 }}>
            <CardHeader
              avatar={
                <Avatar
                  alt="Avatar"
                  src={props.item.image}
                  sx={{ width: 56, height: 56 }}
                />
              }
              title={props.item.id}
              subheader={props.item.name}
            />
          </Card>
        </Box>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
export default UserItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that sx defines an inline style, maybe you can use class to achieve the desired effect

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).